# Preventing automatic variable destruction via dynamic memory management

Tags: c++, dynamic

From what I've understood, dynamic memory allocation can be used to control lifetime of an object. When I "**new**" an object, it stays in memory, on the heap, until I **delete** it.

Now, sometimes things aren't that simple. This is the case in a scenario, in which I'd like to keep certain block of memory reserved, until I free it, preventing destruction of the data in that memory block. For example, I'd like to insert a pointer to an object allocated on the stack into a vector. Whenever a pointer to an object is in that vector, the object the pointer points to cannot be destroyed. This is for safety reasons. How can one accomplish this, reserve a block of memory using dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: Short answer: not possible.

Comment: could you be more elaborate on what you're trying to achieve with this? how much memory do you need? on which system for what purpose? I don't think there is a clean way of doing this with new, but new uses systemcalls like sbrk which allocate large pools you could use placement news to construct objects there. but this is all very dependent on what you'd like to achieve with it.

PS: Smells like Garbage Collection or Leak Detection.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to do do what you want is to use [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer)

You can use:

- [boost smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm)

> "Smart pointers are objects which store pointers to dynamically
>   allocated (heap) objects. They behave much like built-in C++ pointers
>   except that they automatically delete the object pointed to at the
>   appropriate time. Smart pointers are particularly useful in the face
>   of exceptions as they ensure proper destruction of dynamically
>   allocated objects. They can also be used to keep track of dynamically
>   allocated objects shared by multiple owners.
>
> Conceptually, smart pointers are seen as owning the object pointed to,
>   and thus responsible for deletion of the object when it is no longer
>   needed."

- or C++11 smart pointers like [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

> std::unique_ptr is a smart pointer that retains sole ownership of an
>   object through a pointer and destroys that object when the unique_ptr
>   goes out of scope. No two unique_ptr instances can manage the same
>   object.
>
> std::shared_ptr is a smart pointer that retains shared ownership of an
>   object through a pointer. Several shared_ptr objects may own the same
>   object.

Comment: C++ provides its own smart pointers: See `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @stefan I was adding c++11 standard when you commented! Thanks anyway.

Comment: Using a smart pointer doesn't change the lifetime of an auto object, which is one of the things the question  asks about. Proper use of smart pointers can simplify lifetime management, but slapping in a smart pointer whenever a lifetime issue arises isn't a good solution.

Comment: While I like this answer, to me, it seems to be too general-purpose. I try to explain why the best I can. Smart pointers are the thing I would've used anyway because of their secure nature, but the question I asked was more about the fact if it is possible to _utilize dynamic memory allocation to keep stack-allocated variable's memory allocated and therefore preventing automatic, implicit destruction of it_. I know, I know, smart pointers aren't usually explicitly destroyed either, but I hope you get the idea. Did I make myself clear? 0_o

Answer (score 3):

You are close to the solution. The Standard speaks about automatic/dynamic memory management, which is usually a direct translation of stack/heap allocations.

If you want to create an object whose lifetime exceeds the scope in which it is created, then you have to use `new`, but not necessarily directly.

In your case, it seems to me that a simple solution would be to have a `std::vector<MyObject>` and then simply create the object directly in the `vector`. Underneath, it's probably using `new` but you won't have to worry about it: encapsulation rocks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot allocate an object on the stack *and* be sure that it won't be overwritten once the program flow leaves that current function/method and moves on.

If you want an object to be freed if and only if the references to it are zero, then you'll still have to allocate it on the heap and use smart pointers or a garbage collector.